# $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{a} t^k \hat{f}(-t)dt$

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

Let $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be a smooth function with compact support.
Does this limit exist :

$$\lim_{a \to\infty}\int_0^{a} t^k \hat{f}(-t)dt$$

Where $k$ is a fixed natural number and $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$?

Comment: $\widehat{f}$ Swartz function since $C^{\infty}_{00}\subset\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{S})=\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: @Ramanujan, I'm using the same definition as in Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you Kavi Rama and Olivier Diaz for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ belongs to the Schwarz space so does $\hat f$. Hence, $t^{k}\hat f(t)$ is integrable and the limit exists.